# regex to split string by single char string but recognizing pairs of brackets and quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am looking for a way to split a string at a specific character but taking into account some elementary syntax, essentially is detecting matching pairs of brackets and quotes and treating them as a single unit. I am not sure if this is possible with regexp, at least not for my level of expertise.

```
let str="a,pow(3,4),new Value({a:1,b:2}),'{this is a literal, all (this) is a \"single entity'";

let regexp=/what goes here?/;

let arr=str.split(regexp);
```

expected result:

- a
- pow(3,4)
- new Value({a:1,b:2})
- '{this is a literal, all (this) is a \"single entity'

I hope it's not a duplicate, been unable to find a previous reply

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Javascript (I will add it to the question although I think it's not too relevant)

Comment: It's very relevant when you tag it [tag:regex]. JavaScript's regex engine cannot *balance* or recurse, so recognizing pairs of brackets (if there's a possibility of nesting) is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is not supported in `JS` but you can somewhat mimic it:

1. Define what you **do not** want to match and put it in an alternation.
2. Define what you **do want to match** and put it in a capture group
3. Replace the group with sth. that does not occur in your original string
4. Split by this sequence.

---

The expression

```
\([^()]*\)|'[^']*'|(,)
```

... and the `JavaScript` code:

```js
var subject = "a,pow(3,4),new Value({a:1,b:2}),'{this is a literal, all (this) is a \"single entity'";

var regex = /\([^()]*\)|'[^']*'|(,)/g;

replaced = subject.replace(regex, function(m, group1) {
    if (typeof group1 == 'undefined') return m;
    else return "SUPERMAN";
});

console.log(replaced.split(/SUPERMAN/));
```

---

See a demo for the [**expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/FcUBsN/2) and read @ctwheels' comment - the above snippet won't work for recursive subpatterns.

---

You *could* (not saying, you *should*) use a recursive approach in another language supporting recursive patterns, e.g. `PCRE` with

```
(?:(\((?:[^()]*|(?1))*\))|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,
```

This supports nested parentheses as well, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/H6rL10/1/).
Otherwise, you'd need to write a small parser here.

Comment: It's good for what I wanted, thanks. just FYI, when there are nested brackets with commas it doesn't work, "a,pow(3,(4,5)),new Value({a:1,b:2}),'{this is a literal, all (this) is a \"single entity'";

Comment: @Joan: Updated the answer to support nested parentheses (in another language, though).

Answer (score 2):

You are tokenizing a string, so, you may match 1 or more sequences of `'...'`, `(...)` substrings or any chunks of 1+ chars other than a comma.

Use

```
/(?:'[^']*'|\([^()]*\)|[^,])+/g
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hzPW4p/1).

**Details**

- `(?:'[^']*'|\([^()]*\)|[^,])+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `'[^']*'` - a `'`, 0+ chars other than `'` and `'`
  - `|` - or
  - `\([^()]*\)` - a `(` char, 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`, and then `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^,]` - a char other than `,`

See the JS demo:

```js
let str="a,pow(3,4),new Value({a:1,b:2}),'{this is a literal, all (this) is a \"single entity'";
let rx = /(?:'[^']*'|\([^()]*\)|[^,])+/g;
console.log(str.match(rx));
```

Nested parentheses approach:

```js
function splitIt(str) {
    var result = [], start = 0, level = 0, in_par = false, in_quotes = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        switch (str[i]) {
            case '(':
                if (!in_quotes) ++level;
                break;
 
            case ')':
                if (level > 0 && !in_quotes)
                    --level;
                break;
            case "'":
                    in_quotes = !in_quotes;
                    break;
 
            case ',':
                if (level || in_quotes || in_par)
                    break;
                if (start < i) {
                    result.push(str.substr(start, i - start));
                }
                start = i + 1;
                break;
        }
    }
 
    if (start < i)
        result.push(str.substr(start, i - start));
   
    return result;
}

var s = "a,pow(3,(4,5)),new Value({a:1,b:2}),'{this is a literal, all (this) is a \"single entity'";
console.log(splitIt(s))
```

Comment: It works well for the example. But if you nest some brackets with some comma it doesn't work:  let str="a,pow(3,(4,5)),new Value({a:1,b:2}),'{this is a literal, all (this) is a \"single entity'";
Thanks!

Comment: @Joan See an example parser solution that I added to the answer.

Comment: I'd even upvote the parser solution twice - but it's not possible, unfortunately :(

Comment: Its a beautiful solution. As it doesn't use regexp I am not sure if accept the answer; I will wait, thanks a lot anyway.